# Android terminal command to get the current date

Tags: android, time

I am developing on MK808 android stick, I need to set the timezone and date.

For setting the timezone I use -> su -c setprop persist.sys.timezone "America/Chicago"

This command works fine but it won't change the device clock at that time itself I need to reboot my device. After device gets rebooted the device time is changed to CST as expected.

I tried executing command "date" to get the current date. My question is the date which I get from that command should be offset to daylight savings or its not required to offset?

Can someone tell me a solution to eliminate the device reboot after I change the timezone?? So that my device clock should be changed once I change the timezone.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Changing the time zone doesn't change the clock, which is customarily time in seconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC.  It just changes how the time is interpreted.

The `persist.sys.timezone` property is consulted if the `TZ` environment variable is NULL in [tzset_locked](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/jb-mr2-release/libc/tzcode/localtime.c).  Make sure you don't have `TZ` set if you want the property to take effect.

```
% adb shell
# date
Thu Oct  3 13:33:34 PDT 2013
# TZ=US/Eastern date                                                
Thu Oct  3 16:33:38 EDT 2013
```

A quick look at the code in bionic libc indicates `persist.sys.timezone` is checked on every call to `localtime()`.  The property set takes effect immediately:

```
# date
Thu Oct  3 13:39:42 PDT 2013
# setprop persist.sys.timezone US/Eastern
# date
Thu Oct  3 16:39:51 EDT 2013
```

However, that only applies to native code.  The Android framework has its own time zone handling (e.g. you can see it checking the property during [runtime init](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr2-release/core/java/com/android/internal/os/RuntimeInit.java)).